# scrapy href in table

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-shell

I have difficulty extracting `href` from tables.

https://www.asantomediacao.pt/imoveis/

```
<table class="grid tarp tarpRow" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<colgroup>
   <col style="width:160px">
   <col style="">
   <col style="">
</colgroup>
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td valign="top">
         <a href="/imovel/apt-t0-em-condominio-de-prestigio-no-estoril-cascais-re9966av/?rid=17928463" title="Apt T0 em condomínio de prestígio no Estoril | T0 | 1WC">
            <div class="thumbnailframe160">
               <img class="thumbnail" alt="Apt T0 em condomínio de prestígio no Estoril | T0 | 1WC" src="//images.egorealestate.com/Z320x240/S5/C3469/P20281659/Tphoto/ID3b793501-0000-0500-0000-00000d623ecc.jpg" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='/sys/plugins/_res/nopic.png'" border="0">
            </div>
         </a>
      </td>
```

I tried:

`response.xpath('//table[@class="grid tarp tarpRow"]/tbody/tr/td/a/@href').getall()`

`response.xpath('//table[@class="grid tarp tarpRow"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a/@href').get()`

please help me

Comment: Note: `valign` and the other attributes  have been obsolete for many years.

Comment: Where did you check the source code? `tbody` is often shown in the Inpect tool of web browsers, yet often the actual response does not have it. Select “View page source” in your browser to access the actual sources, and find what the HTML code actually looks like.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="tarpInfo"]/a/@href').getall()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are getting `response.status 200` .  don't forget to put the url in  req.

```
In [24]: req =scrapy.Request(url, headers={"USER-AGENT" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) Apple
    ...: WebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 OPR/45.0.2552.888"
    ...: })

In [25]: fetch(req)
2021-01-11 14:42:23 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.asantomediacao.pt/imoveis/> (referer: None)

In [26]: response.xpath('//table[@class="grid tarp tarpRow"]/tbody/tr/td/a')
Out[26]: 
[<Selector xpath='//table[@class="grid tarp tarpRow"]/tbody/tr/td/a' data='<a href="/imovel/terreno-p-moradia-ca...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table[@class="grid tarp tarpRow"]/tbody/tr/td/a' data='<a href="/imovel/terreno-p-moradia-ca...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table[@class="grid tarp tarpRow"]/tbody/tr/td/a' data='<a href="/imovel/terreno-p-moradia-ca...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table[@class="grid tarp tarpRow"]/tbody/tr/td/a' data='<a href="/imovel/terreno-p-moradia-ca...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table[@class="grid tarp tarpRow"]/tbody/tr/td/a' data='<a href="/imovel/terreno-p-moradia-ca...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table[@class="grid tarp tarpRow"]/tbody/tr/td/a' data='<a href="/imovel/terreno-p-moradia-ca...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table[@class="grid tarp tarpRow"]/tbody/tr/td/a' data='<a href="/imovel/apartamento-t2-monte...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table[@class="grid tarp tarpRow"]/tbody/tr/td/a' data='<a href="/imovel/agradavel-apartament...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table[@class="grid tarp tarpRow"]/tbody/tr/td/a' data='<a href="/imovel/agradavel-apartament...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table[@class="grid tarp tarpRow"]/tbody/tr/td/a' data='<a href="/imovel/apt-t0-em-condominio...'>]

In [27]: response.xpath('//table[@class="grid tarp tarpRow"]/tbody/tr/td/a/@href').extract()
Out[27]: 
['/imovel/terreno-p-moradia-cascais-re660db/?rid=6285812',
 '/imovel/terreno-p-moradia-cascais-re658db/?rid=6285795',
 '/imovel/terreno-p-moradia-cascais-re662db/?rid=6285792',
 '/imovel/terreno-p-moradia-cascais-re661db/?rid=6285791',
 '/imovel/terreno-p-moradia-cascais-re657db/?rid=6285794',
 '/imovel/terreno-p-moradia-cascais-re664db/?rid=6285810',
 '/imovel/apartamento-t2-monte-estoril-cascais-re9979db/?rid=17973182',
 '/imovel/agradavel-apartamento-t2-para-arrendar-mobilado-em-zona-nobre-de-cascais-cascais-re9969rf/?rid=17971852',
 '/imovel/agradavel-apartamento-t2-em-zona-nobre-de-cascais-cascais-re9980rf/?rid=17973166',
 '/imovel/apt-t0-em-condominio-de-prestigio-no-estoril-cascais-re9966av/?rid=17928463']
```